# generate 2D matrix from database

Tags: c#

I've a table containing two columns as

[image]

and I want to create a 2D matrix with index fetched from each column like **array [number from first column] [number from second column] = 1**

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr;

            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from BackLinkedPOS", conn);
            da.Fill(dt);

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dr = dt.Rows[i];
                array3[Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), Convert.ToInt32(dr[1])] = 1;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Array generated Successfully!");
        }
```

I've used the following code, but it's giving me wrong matrix. What could be the issue?

I've used a for loop to initialize the array to 0

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arrayCount; j++)
                {

                      array3[i, j] = 0;

                }
            }
```

and the matrix generated is:

[image]

Comment: Post the matrix and the initialization of ´array3`

Comment: post updated with the same.

Comment: What's wrong with the matrix attached? Looks like all ones on their places. Probably you wanted to have indexes? Then subtract one as this: `array3[Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]) - 1, Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]) - 1] = 1;`

Comment: It isn't. Matrix Index [1,6] should be one. Which is not.

Comment: @VarDOS Not sure I understand. `array[1,6]` is one. As it is 0 based and the first argument is a row. See [this help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

According to what you asked, it seems working as expected:
[image: correct matrix]
Remember that the indexes are 0-based, so `array3[1,6]` will be the element at second row and seventh column in your matrix.